# How to disable open browser in CRA?

Tags: reactjs, configuration, create-react-app

I've created a React app using `create-react-app` but whenever I start the dev server (using `npm start`), it opens up my browser. I want to make it so that it doesn't open my browser whenever I start my dev server.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 285, accepted):

Create `.env` file in the root directory where your `package.json` file resides. And add the following:

```
BROWSER=none
```

Now run `npm start`.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? It seems 'react-scripts' has no documentation at all.

Comment: It seems sometimes react-scripts misses the .env file, so in your `package.json`, you can add `"start": ". ./.env; react-scripts start"`

Comment: Note that the default .gitignore does not ignore .env. It does ignore .env.local, so perhaps that is a better filename.

Comment: @JeffreyDrake It's documented [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/).

Comment: If you are using **Windows** go to `packaga.json`  file and right after `"scripts": {` replace  `"start": "react-scripts start",` with `"start": "env BROWSER=none react-scripts start",`

Comment: @BushraMustofa Does not work on windows for me (`'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`). The `.env` file based approach works for me on Windows.

Comment: My answer above will work on `Git Bash` on windows os

Answer (score 106):

Add `BROWSER=none` to your npm start script in your `package.json` file, like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "BROWSER=none react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Check out the CRA documentation for more configuration and environment variable options:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/

---

**Update/Troubleshooting:**

In case you're having a `'BROWSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` error: do an npm install of `cross-env`:

```sh
npm install --save cross-env
```

Then, add `cross-env BROWSER=none` to your `start` script

```
"start": "cross-env BROWSER=none react-scripts start",
```

Comment: If you don't want to install `cross-env` globally, just add `cross-env` to your devDependencies and  use `"start": "npx cross-env Browser=..."`

Answer (score 21):

For **Windows** you can edit/create a script in `package.json` like this one. There must be no blank before the &&:

```json
"start": "set BROWSER=none&& react-scripts start"
```

For **Linux** based OS, just delete the "set" and the "&&" and it will work:

```json
"start": "BROWSER=none react-scripts start"
```

Comment: You can use `cross-env` to have the same way of defining these scripts

Comment: doesnt work for me. no error, it simply ignores the set BROWSER=none on windows for me

Comment: fixed the answer. there must be no blank before &&. no idea why

Comment: Thanks, for suggesting the set BROWSER=none part, I wasted 1 hr search for a way to fix "cannot find BROWSER command"

Answer (score 9):

I suggest doing it at the command level, so you don't have to change any files that get committed.

```
BROWSER=none npm start
```

You can add an alias for this to your shell's configuration:

```
alias myapp-start='cd /path/to/myapp && BROWSER=none npm start'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have InteliJ IDEA you can also on the top right menu click your npm start and Edit Configurations, then in the Environment write:

```
BROWSER=none
```

Of course it will be right there only if you clicked on it in package.json at least once.